# Excel Hyperlink within Hyperlink

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-2007

Cell A1 of Sheet1 has an Hyperlink to a file

Cell A1 of Sheet2 has a Vlookup referencing Cell A1 of Sheet1

How can I make it so(without macros) clicking A1 of Sheet2 also opens the file referenced in A1 of Sheet1?

I have tried Hyperlink(Vlookup ("vlookup logic") ) but it gives "Can't open specified file"

Comment: @ScottHoltzman isn't there a formula that returns the formula of a reference?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure the only thing you need to do is add the hyperlink formula to the vlookup. So:

```
=hyperlink(vlookup(stuff...))
```

Comment: that is what I tried but gives "Can't open specified file" and yes, the original hyperlink is working and the vlookup is correct

Comment: @Mojimi that's odd. I was sure it worked last time I used it. I tried googling it now and it sure does seems to work: https://www.google.se/search?q=excel+vlookup+match+hyperlink&oq=excel+vlookup+match+hyperlink&aqs=chrome..69i57j33l2.19140j0j4&client=ms-android-hms-tmobile-us&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Well I can reference the cell, but not open the file directly